# Running code after returning from an activity

Tags: android, android-activity

On a button clicked, I am creating a new intent and starting an activity.  AFTER the activity returns with a finish(), I want to refresh some of my screen elements. Here is what I am doing

```
private void onButtonClicked() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, myActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(myIntent);
        refreshButtons();
    }
```

My problem is that refreshButtons() gets called as the new intent is loading and not when it returns from the activity. How do I get refreshButtons() to run when I return from the activity I start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void onButtonClicked() {        
Intent i = new Intent(this, myActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        refreshButtons();
    }
```

In myActivity

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Now in your FirstActivity class write following code for the onActivityResult() method.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            refreshButtons();
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}//onActivityResult
```

Comment: Dont forget to call `super.onActivityResult` first and add `@Override` above `onActivityResult`

Answer (score 1):

Use `startActivityForResult` when you call an Intent and when finished that intent onActivityResult method will be called.

```
private void onButtonClicked() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, myActivity.class);
    this.startActivityForResult(myIntent);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    refreshButtons();   
}
```

[For more details read](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: that looks like the "cleanest" way to do it. Works well for me.
But you also need to add a request code at: `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`
and `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` in onActivityResult